# "You got this girls!" seems incorrect to me. How is "you" used to address a team?

Tags: singular-vs-plural

My customer asked me to write
"You got this girls!" on a cake but it's incorrect. What is the proper way to address a team?

Should it be "You've got this girls!" or "You girls have got this!"?

Comment: 'You got this' is casual or informal, especially in the US, but not 'wrong'. If the customer wants it, is it your job to argue? Get the customer to write down what they want and letter the cake accordingly.

Comment: Don't expect such greetings and messages to be written in grammatical English, even in the best educated circles. What exactly is the message that you think the customer wants to convey? And how would you express it?

Comment: 'You got this' is friendly casual, relaxed, informal. It's a cake, not an English lesson. Do what the customer asks, having first got it in writing. "_you/you've got this
mainly US informal used to tell someone that you believe they can or will succeed in dealing with something: I know you can lose that weight! You got this!_ Cambridge Dictionary

Comment: It's okay to put  on a cake.

Answer (score 1):

Strictly speaking, “you’ve got this!” is the correct grammatical way to say it, but it’s equally likely in AmE to say “you got this!” In my opinion, this probably arose simply because some Americans have awful grammar, but it is now pretty widely accepted as casual speech.

Comment: This is actually correct. I remember seeing a "grammar lady" saying that the question in that ad "Got milk?" was not good English. I pointed out to her that it's a shortening of "Have you got milk?" It is true that in general Americans have "awful" grammar though as a professional linguist I wouldn't say that. People just speak like they speak. The got thing is confusing for many English speakers because they don't get (ha ha ha) that have got/have are two forms of the same verb.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, "you've got this" is correct. It's a bit casual and informal, but it's okay if you want to put it on a cake or card. Note that in many informal situations such as greeting, casual conversations, or lyrics, grammatically errors are allowed as long as the meaning doesn't change. For example, is Justin Bieber's song "Boyfriend"

> Real Lyric – ‘If I was your boyfriend, I’d treat you good’
> Correct Lyric – ‘If I were your boyfriend, I’d treat you well.’

or Timbaland "The way I are"

> Real Lyric – ‘Can you handle me the way I are?’
> Correct Lyric – ‘Can you handle me the way I am?’